# Concat serveral pickle files that located in different folders in jupyterlab notebook

Tags: python, pickle, concatenation, glob, jupyter-lab

I have the following path in jupyterlab:

```
Reut/Main_folder/results
```

inside Results there are many folders that contain many pickles files,
for example, in the next path:

```
Reut/Main_folder/results/chicago
```

there are these pickles:
12_05_2020_chic
17_05_2020_chic
23_05_2019_chic

then there is another folder with this path:

```
Reut/Main_folder/results/Berlin
```

with the following pickles:
07_07_2020_ber
01_03_2020_ber
25_02_2019_ber
04_08_2020_ber

I want to concat all the pickles from all the folders together so I get one big pickle.
It's important to say that:

1. I have more than 2 results folders
2. Number of pickles in each result folder is diffeerent.

I have create jupyter notebook in the path:

```
Reut/Main_folder/results
```

and tried:

```
path = r'results'
os.chdir(path)

all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('pkl'))]

combined_pkl = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(f) for f in all_filenames ])
```

but then I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'results'

I have also tried teh same without the path name but that also doesn't work.

I have seen similar posts fro mthe past but they had the files in the same folder and I believe my problem is that I don't understand the logic of the path location compared to the notebook locatio byt maybe i'm wrong.
**I don't find the way to tell jupyter to open each result folder( e.g Berlin, chicago) ,read pickle files and cocnat them.**

**My end goal: to cocncat the pickles from all the files in "results" folder into one big table.**